# Using asterisk for multiple item in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code, I used `*x` to store an uncertain length list.

```
l = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]

for *x, y, z in l:
    print(x)  
    print(y)
    print(z)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
7
8
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
15
16
```

How can I fix the length of lists `x`, `y` like len(x)=4, len(y)=3? The expected output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
8
```

Comment: Just slice it _inside_ the loop, `x = item[:4]` etc.

Comment: Thank you. There are some methods can achieve this by adding another loop in the for loop. I wanna know if I can just modify this line ``for *x, y, z in l:`` to achieve this? I tried init ``x =  [None]*4, y = [None]*4 `` before, but it didn't work.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work :-

```py
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]

for i in lst:
    n = 4

    while any(i):
        print(i[:n])
        i = i[n:]
        n -= 1
    print()
```

What happens here is that, the `for` loop iterates over the main list, then the while loop keeps track of the individual list, then till the `nth` index is printed, and the list is reduced from the `nth` index to the end of the list and keeps continuing this till the list is no more.

Comment: Thank you. There are some methods can achieve this by adding another loop in the for loop. I wanna know if I can just modify this line ``for *x, y, z in l:`` to achieve this? I tried init ``x =  [None]*4, y = [None]*4 `` before, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ricky Mostly I think you can't, because the number of variables that you've to give to the `for` loop depends on **`n`**, and also you've to reduce the list as you iterate through it, so as to achieve that pattern, for this `n` has to be decremented each time. So I think all this can't be achieved in a single line of code.